# ASP MVC - bugged routes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have area I've called forums, now, in thread list page, i have thread links, that are generated like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(title, "Thread", "Forums", new { category = item.CategoryName, item = item.Id, page = 0 }, null)
```

Now, when I open a thread, and I want to get a link to current thread from within a thread, I am doing this (in the thread):

```
@Html.ActionLink(title, "Thread", "Forums", new { category = Model.Post.CategoryName, item = Model.Post.ThreadId, page = Model.Page }, null)
```

Both thread list page and thread page are in the same area.
Now look at both actionlinks together:

```
   1. @Html.ActionLink(title, "Thread", "Forums", new { category = Model.Post.CategoryName, item = Model.Post.ThreadId, page = Model.Page }, null)
   2. @Html.ActionLink(title, "Thread", "Forums", new { category = item.CategoryName, item = item.Id, page = 0 }, null)
```

Those two actionlinks are practically the same (`Model` contains valid data, I've checked), but they are generating different links:

first one:

```
http://localhost:11227/Forums/Thread/1?category=Kosz&page=0
```

second one:

```
http://localhost:11227/Forums/Thread/Kosz/1/0
```

Second one generates correct link, while first one... I have no idea what is first one doing. The **only** difference between them is the place where they are executed, as I said above, fist one is executed in the thread, second one is executed within thread list page.

What can I do to fix that first link?

**UPDATE:** Added route:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Forums_thread",
                "Forums/{action}/{category}/{item}/{page}",
                new { controller = "Forums", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**Second update** I think that i really found some bug? Thanks to Eilon's reply, I found out that this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("something", "Thread", "Forums", new { category = "Kosz", item = Model.Post.ThreadId, page = Model.Page }, null)
```

generates correct link, while this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("something", "Thread", "Forums", new { category = Model.Post.CategoryName, item = Model.Post.ThreadId, page = Model.Page }, null)
```

generates incorrect link (`Model.Post.CategoryName` is still `"Kosz"` though)! I have no idea what is going on...

Comment: What routes do you have, and what, constraints do they have? Also, if you do the *exact* same call to `Html.ActionLink` in each call site, do you get the same results?

Comment: @Eilon: I updated my post with my route, it is first route on my list of routes, so with specified parameters in actionlinks, it should be hit every time. And, hm... Your answer gave me something, i tried calling exact actionlink and it gave me same result on both sites. O.o Gonna try to do sth with it now...

Comment: can you try `@Html.ActionLink("something", "Thread", "Forums", new { category = Model.Post.CategoryName.ToString(), item = Model.Post.ThreadId, page = Model.Page }, null)` that way it will be ensured that `Model.Post>CategoryName` is not null

Comment: Have you met Route Debugger ? This may not resolve your issue but at least this could possibly make it easier to debug.
http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct route below

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Forums_thread",
                "Forums/{action}/{category}/{item}/{page}",
                new { controller = "Forums",category="category", item="item",page = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```